# Protect table update using database role (server role is over)

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-security

I have a database role named app_user with select, update, insert and delete rights on all tables except 2. On this 2 tables app_user role has only select right.

But, some users have right to create database users (using create login, sp_adduser, sp_addrolemember). To be able to execute this procedures they must have sysadmin server role. In this case sysadmin role is over database role app_user and they can update this 2 tables. Currently, I'm giving them securityadmin role but they can execute only create login while creating db users.

To summarize,
I want to protect updating 2 tables for all users except my sysadmin account, and I want some users to be able to create database users (my app executes sp which grant db permission for that kind of users).

Answer (score 0):

You might get a better answer on the DBA site, but it looks like you want to allow the users to execute 3 commands: `CREATE LOGIN`, `CREATE USER` and `sp_addrolemember` (because `ALTER ROLE` can't add members to a role in SQL Server 2008).

According to the documentation, the minimum permissions needed are:

- `CREATE LOGIN` - `ALTER (ANY) LOGIN`
- `CREATE USER` - `ALTER ANY USER`
- `sp_addrolemember` - `ALTER` permission on the role

So they shouldn't need either `sysadmin` or `db_owner` permissions, if you grant them the permissions listed above.